# Does linode load balancers support HTTP long polling and/or websockets?

Tags: websocket, long-polling, linode

Does linode load balancers support HTTP long polling and/or websockets? I couldn't find any info about this on their site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they do, but unfortunately there's not going to be any documentation to help you.   I setup my site [noobniche.com](http://www.noobniche.com) with them and it was a complete pain.  Even a shared host like Webfaction will allow this, but you'll consume your shared hosting plan pretty quickly.  Linode is a pretty good bet, you have complete access to everything.